# How to get "x is friends with x" in me/home using Graph API & Javascript SDk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jsonp, facebook-javascript-sdk

is there a way to do this?

Using the me/home json feed, it shows up as a person and just one image of the person they have friended, even if they have friended several.

Is there a way to pull in all the information?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to achieve this is by using the Graph API Real Time Updates, there's no need to pull the home feed. You should be able to subscribe to the "friends" connection of the "user" object you need so your "callback server URL" will be hit by our servers when that user gets new friends (POST Request).

Note that you will only be able to retrieve the user's new friends public information unless they have previously authorized your App.

Please see further documentation at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Many thanks

Daniel Torvisco - Developer Support Engineer at Facebook